# How to fix this code output is not showing in rat in mace problem

Tags: c

I'm solving this rat in mace problem by recursion.
     A Maze is given as N*N binary matrix of blocks where source block is          the   upper left most block i.e., maze[0][0] and destination block is     lower rightmost block i.e., maze[N-1][N-1]. A rat starts from source and has to reach the destination. The rat can move only in two directions: forward and down.
In the maze matrix, 0 means the block is a dead end and 1 means the block can be used in the path from source to destination. Note that this is a simple version of the typical Maze problem.

This code i write by my own but output is not showing

```
#include <stdio.h>

//#where a[][] means denoting maze and b[][] means solution matrix and i put all zero in b[][]

int move(int a[3][3], int, int);

int recursion(int a[3][3], int b[3][3], int i, int j);

int main() {
  int i, j, n = 3, a[20][20], b[20][20];
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      scan("%d", &a[i][j]);
    print("\n");
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      scan("%d", &b[i][j]);
    print("\n");

  }
  int move(int a[3][3], int i, int j);

  int recursion(int a[3][3], int b[3][3], int i, int j);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
      print("%d", b[i][j]);
    print("\n");
  }
  return 0;
}

int recursion(int a[3][3], int b[3][3], int i, int j) {

  if (move(a, i, j) == 1) {
    b[i][j] = 1;
    if (recursion(a, b, i, j + 1) == 1)
      return 1;
    if (recursion(a, b, i + 1, j) == 1)
      return 1;

    b[i][j] = 0;
    return -1;
  }

  return -1;
}

int move(int a[3][3], int i, int j) {
  int n = 3;
  if (i >= 0 && i < n && j >= 0 && j < n && a[i][j] == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

This code does not show output please help me where is the error                      that its not showing output.

I expect the result will be if i take in maze array
for example a[][] is maze matrix

```
110
101
 111
```

in solution matrix and  print b[][] denoting solution matrix
this is actual solution i want

```
100
100
111
```

everything is fine but output is not showing.
Here i took 3 by 3 matrix to solve only the problem is output is not     showing

Comment: In your recursive function, shouldn't you check for out of range coordinates?

Comment: When you step through the code in a debugger to see exactly what's happening, does it actually go into the `print` block? (And you don't have to repeat *output is not showing* many times in your post. We get it after the first or second time.)

Comment: Use flags when you compile with gcc like `-Wall -Wextra --pedantic` and fix the warnings as if there were errors first. You'll see that you have to change `print` and `scan` with `printf` and `scanf`. I guess you want to call your functions defined outside the main when you rewrite their prototype in the `main`, which is no the proper way to do. Since `recursion` returns an `int`, I'd call it : `int var = recursion(a,b,i,j));` and then having some conditions over this `var`. This'll work if you define `a` and `b` as `a[3][3]` and not `a[20][20]` (same for b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, and welcome to C programming.

There is a lot that is wrong with your code.  The first thing that jumps out at me are the lines:

```
int move(int a[3][3], int i, int j);

int recursion(int a[3][3], int b[3][3], int i, int j);
```

*inside* of your `main()` (lines 22 and 24).  I imagine that what you intend to be doing there is calling `move()` and `recursion()`, but the syntax you are using is for a function *declaration*, not function *calling*.

Second, after both of your loops with `scan()` in them, `i` and `j` are each going to be "3"; I'm betting you want to call `move()` with `i` of "0" and `j` of "0", but that's not the value they will have after those input loops.

Third, speaking of `scan()`, my compiler warns about `scan()` and `print()` being implicitly defined; from context, I'm betting you want `scanf()` and `printf()`.

Fourth, if you are inputing literally:

```
110
101
111

000
000
000
```

then you aren't even making it out of your input loops.  Your input loops perform a total of 18 inputs, so your input would be more like:

```
1
1
0

1
0
1

1
1
1

0
0
0

0
0
0

0
0
0
```

(This is after I replaced `scan()` with `scanf()`, per my note above.)

Fifth, you declare `move()` and `recursion()` as accepting as their first parameters a type `int[3][3]`, but `a` and `b` are of type `int[20][20]`; your input populates (part of) `a` and `b`, but you aren't going to be able to pass `a` nor `b` as the array arguments to `move()` and `recursion()`.

I have not even looked into the logic of your functions.  Likely, there are several other issues, as well.

I strongly recommend you start much smaller and much simpler.  e.g., here's a much simpler program that compiles as-is without warnings, and will give you immediate feedback on what it is doing.  Add to this in small steps, including relevant output lines, so that you can see exactly how it is all taking shape.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int i, j, n = 3, input;

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      scanf("%d", &input);
      printf("input is : %d\n", input);
      }
  }

  printf("i and j are : %d, %d\n", i, j);

  return 0;
}
```

Good luck as you learn C -- there are great things ahead for you!

Comment: Actually stack overflow does not take scan f  so that why i write scan because it highlighted the code with red mark

Comment: @hacksark : do you mean the red underline that shows up when you type "scanf"?  that's just your browser's spellchecker, not SO;  anyway, it's far more important that you supply code that your *compiler* thinks is proper code -- not what your spellchecker thinks is proper

Comment: please tell me   other error my output showing 0 matrix not print the all code

Comment: @hacksark : I'm happy to help, but I've already detailed several fundamental errors with your original code; please start fresh with a smaller, simpler program; I sincerely feel that you are not yet ready for recursive programming -- there are much more fundamental concepts you need to learn first; I recommend a beginning C tutorial with simple examples and exercises; those will be building blocks for a broader, deeper understanding eventually, but the errors here tell me you need to go back and master the basics first; good luck!

Comment: @hacksark : you say "that problem" as if there is just one problem; you have several problems to fix;  I strongly encourage you to go back to the basics : start smaller, start simpler, debug with output lines (or with a debugger), build your code one step at a time and validate with output that every change you make is behaving the way you expect, etc.;  I promise you that the problems you are facing are very, very basic problems and that you need to understand some fundamental things more deeply before you attempt a program like this

Comment: Actually i write another program where its show output